# Given$ X+Y=3 $,$ xy= -10$, find value of $x^2 + y^2$

Tags: arithmetic

Find value of $x^2 + y^2$ given that $x+y= -3$ and $xy= -10$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$x+y=-3$
$$\implies (x+y)^2=9$$
$$\implies x^2+y^2+2xy =9$$
Can you continue?

Answer (score 1):

after squaring we get
$$x^2+y^2+2xy=9$$ with $$xy=-10$$ we obtain $$x^2+y^2-20=9$$
can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

$x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy=(-3)^2-2 \cdot (-10)=...$